# ace-editor DO NOT SHOW in Laravel Voyager

Tags: laravel, ace-editor, voyager

I have a problem with the Voyager Laravel in the BEARD section. ACE-Editor is not displayed in OPTIONAL DETAILS. Here is what is shown right now:

[image: Picture]

Comment: one common cause of issue like this is that container of the editor has height 0, another is editor.resize not being called to check the later  case try resizing window.